# Not able to see social links in YouTube channel backend

Tags: youtube

I am not able to view any social links add button in my channel. Why is that?

This is how it is now:

[image]

And this is how it should actually be:

[image]

I haven't uploaded any videos to my channel.

Answer (score 1):

"Add" button available is to link social media. So,click "Add" provide a title text box and provide your link in URL text box and click "Done" in the right side. This links the social media profiles. You can see similar links in second your attachment. I have attached two screenshots for your reference.

[image: We are adding the link]

[image: This is after adding link]